# How to download files(zip) from a server using scp command for a particular date?

Tags: ssh, scp

I have a Linux server from which i need to download files(server contains many zipped files for a day) to my local machine that is generated for a particular day. is it possible to do so? please help. Thank you

Comment: Yes, if you can obtain the filenames, you can write a command to download them with scp. You will need to find a way to obtain the filenames. If there is a specific naming convention, that is trivial. Otherwsie, you may need to be able to run commands on the server to give you a file listing, or be able to run commands on the server to obtain when the files were last modified, or come up with some other way to select the relevant filenames.

Answer (score 0):

suggesting 2 scripts

show-files.sh on server

```
#!/bin/sh
stat -c "%y %n" * | grep $1 | awk '{print $4}' > files.list
```

copy-files.sh on local machine

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh $1 ./show-files.sh $2
LIST=`ssh $1 cat files.list`
for f in $LIST
do
        scp $1:$f ./
done
```

on local machine call

```
./copy-files.sh SERVER_IP 2023-01-13
```